# Convert minutes and seconds over 60 seconds to whole minutes and seconds

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have times consisting of minutes and seconds displayed with a decimal as a separator, and the seconds can exceed 60 (two digits, so up to 99).  For example, 3.92 equals 3 minutes and 92 seconds.

I need to convert seconds greater than 60 to an additional minute plus the seconds in excess of 60.  So the 92 seconds in this example becomes an additional minute plus 32 seconds.  The result of the conversion would be 4.32.

How can I do that in OpenOffice Calc?

Comment: Edit your question to explain how 3.92 become 4.32

Comment: @Steven I think what Yvonne means is taking 60 off the 3, increasing the minute and reducing the seconds by that 60.  That said, welcome to Super User Yvonne, we are a community here to assist with where you may be going wrong.  Please show us what you have tried to solve this problem yourself to allow us to offer guidance.

Comment: @Stephen What does "taking 60 off the 3" mean?

Comment: subtract .60 from 3.92  and add 1 to 3 =4.32

Comment: the question is unrelated to Windows 10, so I changed the tag to the correct openoffice tag

Comment: Yvonne.  I made an assumption that seconds is limited to two digits.  If so, the rewording is accurate and yass's solution will work.  If that is not the case, and you can have more than two digits of seconds (e.g., 3.156), the question would need to be reworded, and a different solution would be required.  Please clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: It depends how is it written 3.92 or 3:92 the int() will change

Comment: Hi, We are community radio station and our software generates a monthly music report in a csv format.  I use Apache open office calc to edit the report .  In our duration column H5 has the numbers eg. 20600, i insert another column G where i use =H5/3600 and get 5.72 in G5 which i then format to two decimal places and copy in the rest of the column about 3000 songs.  I manually convert each cell in G if it is over .60 seconds because that is what is required before we submit,    I have tried yass formula and yariks but it does not work!!! Help

Comment: @Yvonne, it isn't clear what the 20600 represents, or where 3600 comes from, but if that simple division yields minutes, it is giving you a result of minutes and decimal fractions of a minute, not minutes and seconds.  Trying to treat the decimal portion as seconds and doing this type of manual adjustment is giving you the wrong answer.  Can you provide some more context so we can get you a right answer?  BTW, if you "address" a comment with @, like I did here, the user will be alerted to the post.  Otherwise, they will only know about it if they stumble across it.

Comment: There are 3600 seconds in an *hour*, but that doesn't match the question (e.g. minutes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like the following:
`=IF(A2-INT(A2)>=0.6,A2+1-0.6,A2)`
A2 is your Value 3.92
With if you can test if the decimal part is greater than 0.60
if True it will add 1 to the integer part and subtract 0.60 from the decimal part
if False it will return the same value
A2-Int(A2) to have the decimal part

Comment: This will break for e.g. 3.120: it will return 4.60 instead of 5.

Comment: it depends of number of decimal digit in your case even 3.92 is 3.920, OP just wrote 2 decimals

Comment: Off the top of my head (and a warning about rounding errors with singles and doubles) `int( (a2-int(a2)) /.6)` instead of `1` I think would yield the number of "60 second intervals" contained in the fractional part. But then we'd still need to calculate the fractional part.

Comment: 3:92 will automatically change to 4:32 no need for formula only cell format mm:ss is needed

Comment: see my first comment above ^